# How to called jquery only in IE8 or IE 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 jquery files. Is there code for only IE8 or IE9?

```
<script src=ie8.js></script>
<script src=ie9.js></script>
```

Comment: call those scripts in [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <script src=ie8.js></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>
    <script src=ie9.js></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2):

Check [Condition comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in IE.

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<script src=ie8.js></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>
<script src=ie9.js></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

[IE Conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <script src=ie8.js></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>
    <script src=ie9.js></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: This will consider IE10 too.. which OP might not need

Comment: Ohh.. yes.. you are right. above will consider greater than 7 browsers. Above replies are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <script src="ie.js">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>
    <script src="all.js">
<!--<![endif]--
```

[read](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

Comment: this is good but you are forgetting IE7 and less. and I don't know how IE10 will react to this. :)

Comment: I just know that writing a piece of code only for ie is worst practice. Terrible approach in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The only answer for this could be using [IE Conditional Comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) !